# running replace method multiple times over a column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

I am in a situation where I am having to run `np.replace` multiple times. The goal is to check for strings, such as `CASE 1`, and if I find it, replace it with some other text. For example,

```
list_1 = [
'CASE 1',
'CASE 1B'
]

list_2 = [
'CASE 2',
'CASE 2B'
]

df.col1 = df.col1.replace(list_1, 'found_list_1')
df.col1 = df.col1.replace(list_2, 'found_list_2')
```

This is fine...but as I go, I keep adding more and more `list_n`. How can I use `replace` more concisely? I don't want to have 50 rows of `replace`.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Why can`t you just iterate over the cols?

Comment: I'm not iterating over columns...I'm looking in the same single column multiple times.

Comment: if you are doing a certain task multiple times, u do realize it smells like iteration, right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the difference is "col" whereas your comment said "cols".

Answer (score 1):

Can you just make a list of lists and iterate over it?

```
list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2]
list_replace = ['found_list_1', 'found_list_2']

for i in range(0, len(list_of_lists)):
    df.col1 = df.col1.replace(list_of_lists[i], list_replace[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary:

```
lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
d = {item: 'found_list_{}'.format(idx+1) for idx, lst in enumerate(lists) for item in lst}

d
Out: 
{'CASE 1': 'found_list_1',
 'CASE 1B': 'found_list_1',
 'CASE 2': 'found_list_2',
 'CASE 2B': 'found_list_2',
 'CASE 3': 'found_list_3',
 'CASE 3B': 'found_list_3'}

df.col1 = df.col1.replace(d)
```